# Android : Align Checkboxs

Tags: android, android-layout

**Aim** : Align my `Checkbox`'s view to the left of my `LinearLayout` (**id**=*linearlayout*) !

**The Actual look :**

[image]

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="14">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="13"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"       
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>   
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"            
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"                    
        android:text="text" />        
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: maybe you should add an image of exactly what you are looking for. do you want the checkboxes to line up vertically (if you hold a ruler up to the left side of the checkboxes, you want them all to line up)? or do you want the checkboxes to be to the left of your text?

Comment: another thing to keep in mind, is 1/14 of the width going to be wide enough to hold a checkbox + # for smaller screens? you might want to change your weights a bit. or use a fixed width for the checkbox, and a weight of 1 for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You will need to determine if 100dp is wide enough or too wide for your checkboxes (is it only ever going to be 1 digit, 2 digits, 5 digits?). I also moved margins/padding and gravity to more obvious elements. When using weights, always keep in mind to set the corresponding width or height to 0dp, wrap_content will compete with the weight when the layout is being calculated, and I believe this to be the main reason your checkboxes are not lining up.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="Agadir"
            android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="Casablanca"
            android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="El Jadida"
            android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="Lots of text in this one to stretch the limits of the text view"
            android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="999"
            android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously you only need to pull out one row from the code above, I added multiple to show/test the alignment.

Comment: and if you absolutely must use weights for the checkbox, assign the weight to your TextView and CheckBox appropriately, and set the CheckBox width to 0dp. again, i dont think 13 and 1 will accommodate smaller screens in portrait layout.

Answer (score 1):

Move your checkbox in the same LinearLayout of the TextView, so it will appear at next of the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:weightSum="14">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I removed all the useless LinearLayout wraps, do you really need them?

---

If for some strange reason the answer is: Yes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:weightSum="14">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="13"
            >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="26dp" />

        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i mean by the left linearlayout .. the  parent linearlayout  of my checkbox

Comment: In your layout you have 3 linearlayouts.. can you be more specific? Maybe with an image example

Comment: You still need to keep this linear layout?

Comment: right now you make it more complex. Anyway, if you want to keep it, remove `android:layout_weight="13"` from `TextView` linearlayout and `android:layout_gravity="left" android:gravity="left"` since you don't need it. With this you get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set fix size for the layout with checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `CheckBox` to the left of your `TextView` , you should do like this (just swap two `LinearLayouts`, as you have Horizontal Orientation parent layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:weightSum="14">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_gravity="left"
  android:gravity="left"
>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"            
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"                    
    android:text="text" />        
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="13"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"       
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="26dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i mean by the left linearlayout .. the parent linearlayout of my checkbox